# Why date ("c") produce this strange result?

Tags: php, datetime

```
$now=  date ("c");
```

I used a local Apache server and the result:

> 2015-01-12T23:12:00+08:00

Now here is a problem

Now, at my computer the hour is `22:12` not `23:12`

Also my time zone is Jakarta which is +7 not +8

So why does the code produce `2015-01-12T23:12:00+08:00`

My apache installation got the timezone somewhere. Somewhere wrong. Where?

Comment: -5 from you, -5 from the server or -5 from GMT/UTC? There's quite a few times to measure by...

Comment: what timezone did you set in php? just because your PC is set to a particular zone doesn't mean PHP is.

Comment: How do I know that and where do I set that? Also I want -5 from GMT/UTC

Comment: Is it `date("c")` or `date("d")`? You title and question differ...

Comment: To set the time zone use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)...

Comment: any other ways? It's off only by 1 hour. I wonder where my zend apache installation get the time zone anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta")` at the very top of your PHP file. If that works, change your `php.ini` to always use the correct timezone (`date.timezone="Asia/Jakarta"`). That way, you'll reflect the correct timezone of the server (in this case your computer).

To see what the time is in another timezone, you could do what N.B. suggested in the comments to this answer:

```
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')); //If that's the timezone.
echo $dt->format('c');
```

Comment: Why do you think altering the time zone **globally** is better than, say, using PHP's `DateTime` in conjunction with `DateTimeZone` which let you define time zone based on the user request?

Comment: Is there an easier way? Something that doesn't change the state of other things?

Comment: @SharenEayrs - there is, please check PHP's `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` classes. It's as easy as `$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta')); echo $dt->format('c');`

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to achieve @N.B.. Surely, if you just need the time in another timezone temporarily, you should go about using the DateTime class. Updated the answer to both answer the +7/+8 problem and the "what's the time in another TZ" (the exact same as N.B. stated)

Comment: I don't quite agree with you. If you stick to `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` approach, then all you ever have to know is how to use those two classes (when dealing with dates). You don't have to touch `php.ini`, you don't have to deal with restarting anything, you don't have to worry about accidentally changing default time zone and break some older code that you might have hanging around. It also looks much cleaner and easier to understand. Not planting logical mines is what will most likely keep you sane in the wonderful world of programming :)

Comment: @Dencker - I couldn't agree more :) +1 for providing both possible ways of tackling this problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's server related stuff and you have to reconfigure the timezone of the server. In php.ini check out the value of date.timezone.